# Small bug with `default-mixin`

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, ringsize, testnet

I just noticed that when I type 'set' in monero-wallet-cli [testnet] it prints, among other things `default-mixin = 0`. From what I understand, the default mixin should be the mixin level of a transaction for which none was specified. I sent a transaction like that `transfer [my address] [amount]` and it went through fine, but upon checking it out with `print_tx` I see that indeed it used mixin 4. So I did `set default-mixin 2` and tried sending another transaction. As expected (mixin should be at least 4, right?), I got the message:

`Error: transaction (...) was rejected by daemon with status: Failed`

`Error: Reason: mixin too low`

So it seems that there is a bug in the default-mixin, in that it is using 4 when it is set to zero.

EDIT: I just tried to change it back to how it was at the beginning by doing `set default-mixin 0`, but after doing `set` it prints `default-mixin = 4`. What is going on, it just identifies 4 and 0?

Comment: Good catch, but not really a question. Would you mind reporting the bug [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues)? Fyi, I've used mixin of 2 without problems (2 is the current network minimum while 4 is the wallet default), but I had it specified while using the `transfer` command. Also, the minimum will be bumped up to 4 after the ringCT hard fork.

Comment: @JollyMort: I don't have a github account yet, but I will post it there as soon as I do. In the mean time, please feel free to do that if you'd like.// I think that explains it: since I am using testnet, the minimum mixin of 4 is already enforced?

Comment: Ah, it could be the reason. If you're also using the newest code, there could be some other bugs, too. For the main net I'm not sure if it's planned to enforce 4 at the next HF (rCT optional), or the one after (rCT mandatory). If you intended to post on github, better you do it yourself - that way you could follow-up if any more info is needed etc.